# Ambari ZooKeeper Server install failure

Tags: apache-zookeeper, ambari

When i am installing ZooKeeper Server on the NameNode with Ambari.It throw:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper_server.py", line 179, in <module>
    ZookeeperServer().execute()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/script/script.py", line 219, in execute
    method(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper_server.py", line 70, in install
    self.configure(env)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper_server.py", line 49, in configure
    zookeeper(type='server', upgrade_type=upgrade_type)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_commons/os_family_impl.py", line 89, in thunk
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/ambari-agent/cache/common-services/ZOOKEEPER/3.4.5.2.0/package/scripts/zookeeper.py", line 40, in zookeeper
    conf_select.select(params.stack_name, "zookeeper", params.current_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/libraries/functions/conf_select.py", line 266, in select
    shell.checked_call(get_cmd("set-conf-dir", package, version), logoutput=False, quiet=False, sudo=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 70, in inner
    result = function(command, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 92, in checked_call
    tries=tries, try_sleep=try_sleep)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 140, in _call_wrapper
    result = _call(command, **kwargs_copy)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/resource_management/core/shell.py", line 291, in _call
    raise Fail(err_msg)
resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'conf-select set-conf-dir --package zookeeper --stack-version 2.4.3.0-227 --conf-version 0' returned 1. zookeeper not installed or incorrect package name
```

I am searching from Google,they said "make sure have installed Zookeeper server",and i am installing now(failed).Where is going wrong?How to fix it?

CentOS 7.2,Ambari 2.2.2.0,Zookeeper 3.4.6.2.4,HDP 2.4.3.

Comment: Which stack are you installing and which version? HDP2.4, IOP4.1, etc.?

Comment: Ambari 2.2.2.0, HDP 2.4.3,I completely clear and reinstall,it success,but this problem do not find a reason.

Comment: Check ambari agent log for more detailed error /var/log/ambari-agent/